# How can an application compiled for a particular Linux version be run on any version, when there is no ABI compatibility guaranteed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, lsb

Let us say, an application - JDK, which is compiled against certain the linux version - say 4.18, available for the download.
How can the same application can be run on different linux version - say 3.10?
When there is no ABI compatibility guaranteed by Linux between major releases. ABI compatibility is guaranteed between user program and kernel only when their binaries are generated for the same kernel version as seen from this below picture -
[image]

If my above understanding is correct about the ABI incompatibility between linux versions, then why don't the application developer mention about the linux version on which the binary was generated on. Just like the hardware architecture - x86, x64, ARM, they mention along with the application, which it is compatible with.

Comment: Your figure says that kernel-to-userspace API and ABI are stable...  See the bottom left quadrant.

Comment: [WE DO NOT BREAK USERSPACE!](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/12/23/75) Warning! Strong language.

Comment: @AndyDalton Yes, that's the one even I am referring to. However, that say, ABI is stable for a given version - in this case LSB5. My question is when the version is different.

Comment: @JohanMyréen  Thanks for sharing that article. But contradicting to this I see a comment from RHEL as below - 
To maintain a stable application binary interface (ABI), Red Hat does not update the kernel version, but instead backports new features to the same kernel version with which a particular version of RHEL has been released
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux

Comment: You may have gotten that image from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base.  Note there _While the LSB is a standard and without a competitor, it is followed only by few Linux distributions._  LSB might not be the best metric by which to measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel ABI exposed to userspace [is supposed to be stable](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/12/23/75), that is to say, if a program which works on a given kernel stops working on a later kernel, that’s considered a serious bug and will usually be fixed. If the bug affects any release in a stable series of the kernel, its fix will also be backported.

When you see references to the RHEL kernel ABI, and feature backports to that older kernel, that’s above and beyond the kernel ABI stability “promised” by the upstream kernel developers.

For applications, libraries are a much greater concern than the kernel, and support varies across distributions. See for example [the RHEL 7 compatibility guide](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-abi-compatibility) (and note that it doesn’t mention the kernel). This is what [the LSB](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/lsb.shtml) is mostly concerned about: it lists libraries which applications can rely on (on LSB-compliant distributions), along with their sonames.

Comment: So if you mean that there will always be backward compatibility between kernel versions. ie, if an application works on linux kernel 2.16, then it is suppose to work on 3.12 as well. In that case, why RHEL dont upgrade their kernel, within the same major release? The reason, they provide is that it may be cause ABI incompatibility. Can you explain me this?

Comment: The RHEL kernel ABI addresses the lower-right quadrant, *i.e.* out-of-tree modules; maintaining a fixed kernel ABI allows users to continue using their modules throughout a release’s lifetime.

Comment: This kinda started clarifying things. So "out-of-tree" indicate piece of software which is related to kernel and not the user application, is it? 
So linux kernel guarantees ABI compatibility between userland application and kernel across versions. However, same is not guaranteed between kernel modules to kernel interaction across versions...

Comment: Yes, that’s the split between the left side of the diagram in your question, and the right side. Everything on the left is used by software outside the kernel; everything on the right is used by software inside the kernel or loaded into the kernel (*i.e.* modules).

Comment: Okay. Got it. That diagram brought in a confusion since on the left bottom quadrant they mentioned about ABI stability across Linux distribution on a given kernel version and didn't mention that ABI stability is maintained across versions for user applications.

Comment: The lower-left quadrant mentions “LSB 5.0”, but that’s not a kernel version, it’s a version of the LSB. The lower-left quadrant is supposed to indicate that binaries built to match a given version of the LSB can run on any distribution supporting that version of the LSB.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Stephen for clarifying.
I will checkout more on what LSB is understand this better.
I am going to ACCEPT this answer, including the clarification provided in the comment section.